# i want to add to the default value

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to add 10 to $counter. It works when i change it from counter + 10 to counter++ but it will increment by 1

```
int counter = 0;
   
 _incrementCounter10() {
    setState(() {
      counter + 10;
    });
  }

Text('$counter')

 InkWell(onTap: (){_incrementCounter10;})
```

Comment: you want to add 10 every time function calls or as Initial Value?

Comment: you can write like this :  counter = counter + 10;
  instead of   counter + 10;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add 10 in your **$counter** variable you can edit your **setState()** function from

```
counter + 10;
```

to

```
counter += 10;
```